# How to use Gurobi quicksum in Python

Tags: python, gurobi

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to write this constraint for Gurobi in Python.

Is this the right way?

```
model.addConstr(
    (gp.quicksum(a[i,r]*y[r] for i in range (len(n))) for r in range(len(R)))==1 , name='firstConst')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always try to use Python iterators directly instead of using `range(len(R)`.

So, a better way of writing these constraints (there are actually `|P|` many) is

```
for i in P:
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(a[i,r]*y[r] for r in R) == 1, name='firstConst')
```

You can also create a set of similar constraints in a single call using [addConstrs()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html):

```
model.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(a[i,r]*y[r] for r in R) == 1 for i in P), name='firstConst')
```

You should also add your variables in a similar manner:

```
y = model.addVars(R)
```